# How to fit 3 table in landscape mode in mobile phone?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

The 3 table already fit in landscape mode, but theres column that doesnt look good, like JAM column. How i can fix this problem?
I already use responsive table from bootstrap.

Here is the HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>

    <title>Table Grid Responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="styles-mediaquery-reporter.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> 

</head>
<body>


    <hgroup>
            <h1>Table Media Queries &amp; Responsive Grid</small></h1>
            <h2>Quick-Tip &raquo; with a Little CSS3 MediaQuery-Reporter</h2>
    </hgroup>
        <div class="span-one-third">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table border = '1' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover lebarTabel">
                <th colspan = '3' class="text-center">SHIFT PAGI</th>
                <tr>
                    <td  class="text-center j_a">JAM</td>
                    <td  class="text-center g_i" >GIL/<br>JAM</td>
                    <td  class="text-center s_d">S/D</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>06-07</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(6) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(6) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>07-08</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(7) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(7) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>08-09</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(8) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(8) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>09-10</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(9) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(9) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10-11</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(10) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(10) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11-12</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(11) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(11) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12-13</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(12) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(12) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>13-14</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(13) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(13) ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span-one-third">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table border = '5' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover lebarTabel">
                <th colspan = '3' class="text-center">SHIFT SIANG</th>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center j_a">JAM</td>
                    <td class="text-center g_i">GIL/<br>JAM</td>
                    <td class="text-center s_d">S/D</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>14-15</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(14) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(14) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>15-16</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(15) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(15) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>16-17</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(16) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(16) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>17-18</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(17) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(17) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>18-19</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(18) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(18) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>19-20</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(19) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(19) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>20-21</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(20) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(20) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>21-22</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(21) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(21) ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span-one-third">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table border = '5' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover lebarTabel">
                <th colspan = '3' class="text-center">SHIFT MALAM</th>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center j_a">JAM</td>
                    <td class="text-center g_i">GIL/<br>JAM</td>
                    <td class="text-center s_d">S/D</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>22-23</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(22) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(22) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>23-00</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(23) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(23) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>00-01</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(0) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(0) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01-02</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(1) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(1) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02-03</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(2) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(2) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>03-04</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(3) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(3) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>04-05</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(4) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(4) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05-06</td>
                    <td id="dari" align="center" class="gil"><?php echo $obj->tampil_hasil(5) ?></td>
                    <td id="sd"   align="center" class="sd"><?php echo $obj->tampil_sd(5) ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

HERE IS THE CSS CODE

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape){
    .span-one-third {
        width: 33.333%;
        float: left;
        /*display:inline-block*/
    }


}
```

HERE IS THE RESULT PIC
[image]

Comment: add jsfiddle or some online compiler of your code ..

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this.

**1.** Make table responsive like below code but it will add horizontal scroll on same screens.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        ...
      </table>
</div>
```

**2.** You can adjust font size and padding/margin on small screen devices to make it look better.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .table thead > tr > th,
  .table tbody > tr > th,
  .table tfoot > tr > th,
  .table thead > tr > td,
  .table tbody > tr > td,
  .table tfoot > tr > td {
      padding: 1px;
      font-size: 6px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .table thead > tr > th,
    .table tbody > tr > th,
    .table tfoot > tr > th,
    .table thead > tr > td,
    .table tbody > tr > td,
    .table tfoot > tr > td {
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .table thead > tr > th,
    .table tbody > tr > th,
    .table tfoot > tr > th,
    .table thead > tr > td,
    .table tbody > tr > td,
    .table tfoot > tr > td {
        padding: 3px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```